# Visual Studio WebAPI Moq Setup Repository to return object, return empty list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, moq

I am writing a webAPI unittest with Moq. I have been following the example to mock dependencies and pass them to the service api which call the repository api. I setup the mockRepostory to return a valid list of 1 object but got back an empty list. I looked at the the mockRepository Setup and don't see why it is not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is my unit test

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void GetUsers()
{
    Mock<IUsersRespository> mockRepository = new Mock<IUsersRespository>();
    var mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

    mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<User, Users>(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(new Users());
    mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<Users, User>(It.IsAny<Users>())).Returns(new User());


    User mockUserRecord = new User{ UserId = 1, Title = "View Only", Description = "permission to view" };
    var mockUserList = new List<Users>();
    mockUserList.Add(new Users { UserId = 1, Title = "View Only", Description = "permission to view" });

    Users request = new Users { UserId = 0, Title = "", Description = "" };


    // here I setup the return object, but it not return that.
    mockRepository.Setup(s => s.GetUsers(request)).Returns(mockUserList.AsEnumerable());

    var mockUserService = new UsersService(mockRepository.Object, mockMapper.Object);

    var result = mockUserService.GetUsers(new User { UserId = 0, Title = "", Description = "" });
    // the Get call returns an empty list
            
    mockUserService.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

Here is my Service API

```cs
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(User request)
{
    Users _request = mapper.Map<User, Users>(request);
    var UserModel = UsersRespository.GetUsers(_request);
    var UserViewModel  = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Users>, IEnumerable<User>>(UserModel);

    return UserViewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup, you have this

```cs
mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<User, Users>(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(new Users()); // This seems ok
mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<Users, User>(It.IsAny<Users>())).Returns(new User()); // This seems to be where the issue is
```

Your service is mapping to and from an `IEnumerable`:

```cs
var UserViewModel  = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Users>, IEnumerable<User>>(UserModel);
```

The second mock setup should be

```cs
// T in "It.IsAny<T>()" should be the type of the local variable UserModel
mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<IEnumerable<Users>, IEnumerable<User>>(It.IsAny<???>())).Returns(new List<User> { User() } );
```

In summary, these are the things that look off:

1. The generic parameters of `Map` are not correct.
2. The return value of `Map` is not correct
3. *Possibly* the input parameter of `Map` is not correct, but I can't confirm this from the code above.

Comment: That is mocking the automapper, which has been done. I was doing the set with mockRepository.Setup(s => s.GetUsers(request)).Returns(mockUserList.AsEnumerable()); which is not working.  The mock GetUsers should return a valid list object.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code that it works  better to mock the respository.GetUsers.